# How do you write a query that returns an ordered list starting from a specific item?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

If you have table with {1,3,4,5,9,15,43} how do you write a query that returns the three items following "5" in the natural sort order?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.table
  .Where(x=>x.field>5)
  .OrderBy(x=>x.field)
  .Take(3);
```